# Retrieving user phone number from a Facebook app

Tags: facebook, sms

Now I read that the extended permission which allowed developers to send SMS through their app  was deprecated some time ago. And I [read](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2375888,00.asp) about Facebook again granting permission to  developers to extract user phone numbers then again it getting cancelled [temporarily](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2375899,00.asp).

I want to know if they re-enabled this feature? or is it gone for good? I did a search on Google on this but didn't come across an updated version of this story.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API - How to get user's address, phone #?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3402270/facebook-api-how-to-get-users-address-phone)

Comment: @ifaour I'm not asking _how_ to get the phone number. I want to know if that feature is available now or not.

Comment: Have you followed the links? it's not (***yet***?) available and no response from Facebook on when to have it back. Hopefully @Igy would see this and get back to us with useful info.

Comment: @ifaour I see. That's a bummer. Thanks anyway.